# video is not playing in windows safari browser version 5.1.7

Tags: wordpress, html

I've put a video(HTML5 tag) on front page.It is working good in Mozilla and Chrome, but not working in safari windows(ver 5.1.7)
This is site [URL](http://dev.codeholic.in/priyank/parklane_new/)

Here is the code I put:

```
    <div id="slideshow" class="clearfix"> 
          <div id="home_video" class="clearfix" align="center">
            <div class="video-js-box">
              <video class="video-js" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="true" preload="auto" tabindex="0" muted autoplay loop>
                <source type="video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"" src="<?php echo site_url();?>/wp-content/uploads/parklane_low1.mp4"></source>
                <source type="video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"" src="<?php echo site_url();?>/wp-content/uploads/parklane_low1.webmsd.webm"></source>
                <source type="video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"" src="<?php echo site_url();?>/wp-content/uploads/parklane_low1.oggtheora.ogv"></source>
                <object id="flash_fallback_1" class="vjs-flash-fallback" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
                  <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
                  <param name="allowfullscreen" value="false" />
                  <param name="flashvars" value='config={"playlist":["http://www.yourwebsite.com/cms/video/poster.jpg", {"url": "<?php echo site_url();?>/wp-content/uploads/parklane_low1.mp4","autoPlay":true}]}' />
                </object>
              </video>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Please provide any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try Iframe except HTML5 Video tag, here is code for that

```
   <div id="slideshow" class="clearfix"> 
      <div id="home_video" class="clearfix" align="center">
        <div class="video-js-box">
           <iframe class="video-js" src="<?php echo site_url();?>/wp-content/uploads/parklane_low1.mp4" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And if you to change with js, please use $( window ).load
except $( document ).ready event. It works in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks for reply shahid.

Comment: please check your video size if it is to large file then it take time to load so you have to hold for a while. and another thing please inspect element copy video link and paste it into new tab of safari browser. if it work then check witch tag safari browser insert for playing video then try that one.